# Как вывести HTML из PHP?

Tags: html, php

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести любой HTML код из PHP скрипта? Просто, если выводить обычной командой echo, то будет выводиться просто символы, которые в HTML переводиться не будут.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не совсем понял вопрос. Если вы хотите вывести html из php, то echo все нормально выведет.

```
echo '<a href="#">link</a>';
```

выведет ссылку. Если же вам нужно вывести спецсимволы, пропустите текст через htmlspecialchars():

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<a href="#">link</a>');
```

выведет `<a href="#">link</a>`.

Comment: Знаете что такое uCoz? Я использую этот бесплатный хостнг. Там есть функция создания меню сайта($SMENU_1$). Так вот, в PHP скрипте я вывожу через echo $SMENU_1$, но меню не выводит этот спецсимвол от uCoz, а пишет просто $SMENU_1$ вместо появления менюшки. Надеюсь нормально объяснил.

Comment: К сожалению, с Юкозом я вам помочь не смогу, так как не работал с его шаблонизатором и не знаю, работает ли там вообще пользовательский php. Да и с точки зрения здравого смысла, echo '$SMENU_1$' - это просто вывод строки $SMENU_1$ в обход шаблонизатора. Лучше просто пропишите в нужном месте шаблона $SMENU_1$.